# How to trigger execution of a unix script upon switching to a directory where the script resides

Tags: unix

I want to execute a script that creates environment variables for the user when they traverse to a certain directory.

Comment: Short of overloading "cd" or patching your shell, you cannot do that.

Comment: can you "overload" cd?? it's builtin. you can use alias, but how are you going to pass parameters?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you had a real example of how you expect to use this, but based on you headline and question body how's this for a start?

```
 cat specialVarSetter.bash
 #! /bin/bash

 targetDir=/path/to/special/dir
 cd $1

 if [[ $PWD == "$targetDir" ]] ; then
    userVar1=xxxx
    userVar2=yyyy
 fi

 #your real stuff goes after this
 runProgram 1
 runProgram 2
```

Use like

```
 chmod 755 specialVarSetter.bash
 specialVarSetter.bash /path/to/special/dir
```

If you just want the user to enter 'dir', then you can add something like `baseDir=/path/to/special` and change to `cd $baseDir/$1`. The test will execute and you'll get your variables set.

Also, I think csh/tcsh may have such a feature natively, and if tcsh has it, then zsh will have it too (and may have it anyway). It depends on how much control you have on your user environment. (I'm thinking of something named like CDPATH or related?, zsh people, a little help?)

I hope this helps.